# Tweepy - Get Id of retweeted tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Does anyone know how this is done? I'm trying to get the id of the original tweet. So if someone retweets something, I want to find what they retweeted. This is what I have to determine what is retweeted or not:

```
if hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'): #if not rt'd
        #something
else:                                   #if rt'd
        #something
```

Comment: anything else..... ? any code? Any attempts ?

Answer (score 4):

The field `retweeted_status` contains the representation of the original tweet that was retweeted to generate the `status` object you have with you. So every field that is present in a twitter status object is included as such in the `retweeted_status` field. Now all you have to do is to get them like

```
status.retweeted_status.id_str
```

to get the id of the parent tweet, for instance. Simply modify this accordingly to get whatever field you need from the parent tweet.

Comment: and how do you retweet the  original tweet that we received in the status object